# Elementary Combination Question

Tags: combinations

An ice cream sundae at an ice cream shop consists of 3 different types of ice cream and 2 different types of topping. If there are 12 different types of ice cream and 8 different toppings to choose from, how many different sundae's can a customer create?

My approach: $$_{12}C_3 * {_8}C_2=6160$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks fine, it seems explicit that you can't have $2$ scoops of durian and one of chocolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct.

Let me explain:

Since ice-cream and topping are independent, $$#of sundays=#of icecreams * #of toppings$$

If types of ice-cream didn't have to be different your result would be $12^3$

Now you have to choose one flavor (12 ways), then a different flavor (11 ways) and then a third one (10 ways). So your result would be $12*11*10$.

But keep in mind that you are not interested in the order of the flavors. There are $3!$ ways of ordering the 3 flavors. So, your true number of different ice-creams is$\frac{12*11*10}{3!}$ which is $_{12}C_3$.

Same way for toppings.

If you define as different sundae a sundae where the order of the ice-creams or the order of the toppings is different, then your result would be $(12*11*10)*(8*7)$